# Excel or Power Query: Merge/Lookup Closest Previous Date

Tags: excel, join, merge, powerquery, lookup

everyone:

I have a table with these dates:

[image]

I have another table with a list of dates and owners:

[image]

I need to merge/join these two tables so that the transaction dates are matched up with the closest previous start date so that it looks like this:

[image]

I tried using XLOOKUP with "-1" but that was a problem because XLOOKUP retrieved the first record for transaction date 4/16/2017 (which has 2 matches) and I couldn't merge on Power Query since there are no exact date matches. Is there another way?

Thank you.

Comment: Search for examples of "top 5" to see how to handle duplicates, hint aggregate().

Comment: But I think there will be more to this question. As in once you get an answer you will ask about doing y as well.

Comment: You can reuse the code from this answer by horseyride: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825564/merging-two-tables-by-the-closest-date-and-id-in-power-query

It also helps if you post text or file attachments rather than images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this table is named Table4, you first need to group because of your duplicate dates for e and f.

[image]

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table4"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Start Date", type text}, {"Owner", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Start Date", type date}}, "en-US"),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type with Locale", {"Start Date"}, {{"All", each _, type table [Start Date=nullable date, Owner=nullable text]}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

Assuming this table is named Table3, you can then add a custom column as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69825564/merging-two-tables-by-the-closest-date-and-id-in-power-query)

[image]

The code for this table is

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table3"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Transaction Dates", type text}}),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Changed Type", {{"Transaction Dates", type date}}, "en-US"),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type with Locale", "Custom", (i) => Table.Last( Table.Sort( Table.SelectRows(Table4,each [Start Date] <= i[Transaction Dates]),{"Start Date", Order.Ascending}))),
    #"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Start Date", "All"}, {"Custom.Start Date", "Custom.All"}),
    #"Expanded Custom.All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Expanded Custom", "Custom.All", {"Owner"}, {"Owner"})
in
    #"Expanded Custom.All"
```

[image]

Comment: Hardly any questions lately, and all of them about API interfaces which I have no interest in answering. It's like the entire place has died

Comment: we could do a chat group if you want https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145314/horseyride